# UINavigationController with UITableView in modal popup (on iPad)

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, modal-dialog, ipad

**Short Version:**

"How do you get a simple UITable drill down UINavigationController-styled non-full-screen modal dialog on the iPad?"

**Long version:**

I have a very specific set of requirements that I can't seem to get working...

I have a functioning iPad program that that needs to pop up a non-full-screen modal view.  This modal needs to have a navigation controller and a simple drill-down table that displays a detailed view that I can have edit some values related to the selected item in the table.

Of course I am looking to have the regular "Back" and "Delete" buttons in the Navigation Bar.

I can handle the detailed view, what I am having issues with:

1. Non-full-screen popup (mine is
   always full screen no matter what I
   try).
2. The Navigation controller will not display the Table View I tell it to and the navigation bar does not even have the title I assigned to it in IB.

I can't seem to get any of this working.  If anyone has a step by step example of how to do this, that would be great,

~Eric

P.S.  I am not afraid of doing this 100% programmatically, but all the examples I have been trying to follow (and failing at extending to my problem) use IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the fullscreen issue, you need to set `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` or `UIModalPresentationPageSheet` on the controller you want to present modally. I'm not sure of a way to do this through IB.

As for your navigation controller/table view, I think more information is needed to provide an answer.

Comment: What information would you like?  Also, I am setting that property on the controller I pop from.

Comment: Where/how are your nav controller and table view created? What's connected to what in your XIBs? How are you presenting the modal view (code)? I assume you have a `UITableViewController` setup somewhere to manage your table view?